Need help debugging constantly increasing JVM memory usage
This is my first post ever here, so please excuse me if I missed something.
I have a Spring Boot (3.2.9) application running inside Kubernetes (k3s) with Java 21 (Adoptium JDK Ubuntu Jammy image).
We are struggling to specify the container.limits.memory value as our application ends up being killed by OOMKiller.
The application is started using the following command line
          java \
            -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail \
            -XX:StartFlightRecording=delay=1m,duration=8h,maxsize=2g,settings=profile,filename=/data/uaa.jfr \
            -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal \
            -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 \
            -Xms128m \
            -Xmx256m \
            -XX:+UseG1GC \
            -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m \
            -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m \
            -Xlog:gc:file=/tmp/gc.log \
            -Dserver.port=10000 \
            -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
            -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
            -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 \
            -Dspring.profiles.active=core \
            -Dspring.config.import="kubernetes:" \
             -jar \
             /opt/backends/uaa.jar

As you can see, I have set different memory limits to no avail. For testing purposes, I have given the POD a limit of 5 GB. Since app startup, for 2 hours I have recorded the memory usage using JFR but I am only able to find out that the "Total Size" shown in Java Mission Control is increasing. The value shown as "Total Size" roughly matches the output shown in "kubectl top pod" over time.
I am unable to figure out why it is increasing and how to prevent it. The 3 limits specified above (heap, meta space and direct memory size) should ensure no more than 768 MB + (around 5%) additional data not handled by those 3 parameters. Note that I have tried setting lower sizes, but no matter what I set, I still eventually end up with OOMKiller killing the POD.
Any help on where to look next for a memory leak or any additional limit options I can set with Java 21 could be useful.
For reference, here are some screenshot of the memory usage from JFR analysis
Memory usage at Startup
Memory usage after ~1 hour of runtime
JFR events related to native memory usage
kubectl top pod output at ~142 minutes of runtime
NAME                   CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
uaa-85bf44c694-t8qxf   18m          1028Mi


Do your app use any native libs?

It seems that netty is in use by artemis-client, pulled in by spring-boot-starter-artemis. I will examine the marked duplicate task and try to find out what I missed.
